# Fragment Error - ListFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment view that needs replacement with another fragment.

When the ListFragment item is selected, the DetailsFragment is to be replaced with another ListFragment by passing along Extras to the new ( or 2nd) ListFragment in the activity. My problem is that I am getting a "No Activity found to handle Intent {(has extras)}". The ListFragment works fine when the activity first starts, but when i up date (replace) the Details activity with another ListFragment, I get the error.

This is my first Fragment activity and I guess I don't know how to pass Extras properly between  the fragment. I am most surely not using the fragment-manager/transaction classes properly(?).  If anyone could correct my implementation, I would greatly appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** I added "i.setClass(getActivity(), ListFragment.class);" to the intent in the ListFragment class and now the Log error has changed to the following:

**UPDTATE 2:** I corrected my intents to Arguments as Devunwired sugested and it works just beautifully now.  Thnx Devunwired.  the onlyn issue I have now is that the backstack doesnt work when the back key is pressed. The corrected class is below:

LogCat **(UPDATED)**:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.andaero.test/com.andaero.test.fragments.ListFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.andaero.test.fragments.ListFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.andaero.test.fragments.ListFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

The ListFragment Class:

```
public class ListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment {

    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    protected TextView activityTitle;

    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    File dbfile = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/Andaero/dB/Andaero.db");
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

    private static final String QUERY_KEY = "QUERY_KEY";
    private static final String QUERY_ORDER = "QUERY_ORDER";

    private View layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        return layout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        Bundle arg = this.getArguments();//**ADDED TO GET THE ARGS

        /**
         * Get the query string from last activity and pass it to this
         * activity-----------------------------------------------------
         */
        String q = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            q = extras.getString(QUERY_KEY);
        }

        if (arg != null) {
        q = (String) (getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(
                "QUERY_KEY") : 1);
    }

        loadQuery(q);
    }

    public void loadQuery(String q) {

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            String qO = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q + " ORDER BY `_id` " + qO, null);
            setListAdapter(new QueryAdapter(getActivity(), c));
            db.close();

        } else {
            Alerts.sdCardMissing(getActivity());
        }
    }

    public class QueryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public QueryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View v, Context context, final Cursor c) {

            int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
            String label = c.getString(tvLabel);
            final TextView labelTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);

            if (labelTxt != null) {
                labelTxt.setText("(" + label + ")");
            }

            int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
            final String title = c.getString(tvTitle);
            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

            if (titleTxt != null) {
                titleTxt.setText(title);
            }

            int tvDescription = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description");
            String description = c.getString(tvDescription);
            TextView descriptionTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.caption);

            if (descriptionTxt != null) {
                descriptionTxt.setText(description);
            }

            int tvDate = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date");
            String date = c.getString(tvDate);
            TextView dateTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);

            if (dateTxt != null) {
                dateTxt.setText(date);
            }

            int tvGoto = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gotoURL");
            final String gotoURL = c.getString(tvGoto);
            TextView gotoTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

            if (gotoTxt != null) {
                gotoTxt.setText(gotoURL);
            }

            gotoTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.setTag(gotoURL);

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setEnabled(true);
            lv.setClickable(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

                    // Create new fragment and transaction
                    Fragment newFragment = new ListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();

                    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with
                    // this fragment,
                    // and add the transaction to the back stack
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    String url = "";
                    url = (String) v.getTag();

                    int nI = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("intent");
                    String intent = c.getString(nI);
                    Class<?> myIntent = null;
                    try {
                        myIntent = Class.forName("com.andaero.test.fragments"
                                + intent);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Class Not Found for new intent!");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
                    String title = c.getString(tvTitle);

                    int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
                    String label = c.getString(tvLabel);

                    String queryKey = "SELECT * FROM " + label;
                    c.close();
                    db.close();

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();//**REPLACED THE INTENTS
                   args.putString("QUERY_KEY", queryKey);
                   args.putString("KEY_URL", url);
                   args.putString("KEY_SUBTITLE", title);
                   args.putString("KEY_LABEL", label);
                   args.putString("KEY_INTENT", intent);
                   args.putString("QUERY_ORDER", "ASC");

                   newFragment.setArguments(args);

                    // Commit the transaction
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with using the `FragmentTransaction` to replace one `Fragment` with another, but `Fragment` doesn't use an `Intent` to pass data from one instance to another like `Activity` does.  In fact, calling `startActivity()` with an `Intent` pointed at a `Fragment` will cause all kinds of fireworks that you don't want (like you've seen).

It is perfectly okay to pass data to a new `Fragment` in its constructor, so you can create a constructor for your `ListFragment` that takes any parameters of data you want to forward.  Another option is to set all of your "extras" as arguments on the new `Fragment` by putting them in a `Bundle` and using `Fragment.setArguments()`.  Any time you want to access the arguments you attached to the `Fragment`, you can just call `getArguments()` to get back that same `Bundle`.  So basically, replace all the code having to do with an `Intent` in your `onItemClick()` method, and instead:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("QUERY_KEY", queryKey);
//...add all the extras to the bundle

newFragment.setArguments(args);

transaction.commit();
```

Also, off-topic, but you might want to rename your `Fragment` to something else so that you don't have to rely on the fully qualified package name to tell the difference between your `ListFragment` and the platform's version in your code.

HTH

Comment: Thnx fot the help on this. I dont get the error now and the activity loads but all it does is reload the data that was currently there: it doesnt load the new data into the list as it did when the classes were set up w/o fragments.  Any more help/pointers. Thnx

Comment: Again thnx for the help with this. Could you take a look at my changes and see if there is a better way I should implement my Args and also do you see why my back stack doesnt work with the back key??

Comment: I don't see anything apparent as to why the back action is not working.  The transaction is being added to the back stack, so hitting the back button should pop the last transaction to its previous state.  Do you have `onBackPressed()` overridden in your Activity without calling `super` or something else that would affect standard back behavior?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just create a constructor that you pass the values into when you create the fragment? It seems that is what you are looking to do

Comment: Because its bad to use constructors in fragments. You always need the default constructor (empty) or it will break when restored...